# Could we solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx$ and what does it say about $\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos(x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, summation, improper-integrals

As the title states: **Could we solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx$ and what does it say about $\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos(x)$?**

It is clear we can't solve this using the fundamental theorem of Calculus, but I thought it would be solvable as a summation.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx=\lim_{u\to\infty}\lim_{v\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{u}\frac{v\sin(\frac{vi}u)}{u}$$

I figured this would be hard to solve, so I went a different path:

Noting that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)dx=2$$$$\int_{n}^{n+\pi}\sin(x)dx=-\int_{n-\pi}^{n}\sin(x)dx$$For $n=m\pi$, $m=0,1,2,3,\cdots$

Trying to put this all together, I arrive at 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^i2=2-2+2-2+\cdots$$This summation evaluates to equal:
$$2-2+2-2+\cdots=1$$So, I argue that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx=1$$
Furthermore, going back to the fundamental theorem of Calculus, we have:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx=\lim_{p\to\infty}-\cos(p)-[-\cos(0)]$$$$=-\lim_{p\to\infty}\cos(p)+1=1$$
Therefore, we have
$$-\lim_{p\to\infty}\cos(p)=0=-0=\lim_{p\to\infty}\cos(p)$$

Am I wrong?  If so, what does the indefinite integral evaluate to and what does it mean for $\lim_{p\to\infty}\cos(p)$?

Comment: How do you get to $2-2+2-2+\ldots =1$? That is not the value of this sum in the general sense as value of a series.

Comment: @Hirshy It is oscilating and similar to $1-1+1-1+\dots=.5$, I'm looking up what the summation method is called.

Comment: Also $1-1+1-1+\ldots=0.5$ is not the value of the series. This can be achieved e.g. by [Ramanujan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) which has nothing to do with integrals and riemann sums. You can assing a value to this sum which makes sense to some extent, but you can't expect to use this value in other applications.

Comment: @Hirshy Really?  Then what's the point of being able to "evaluate" something like that?  (probably nothing?)

Comment: The series $\sum (-1)^n$ is Cesàro-summable to $\frac{1}{2}$. We can do something analogous for integrals, and say that (the locally integrable function) $f$ is C-integrable to $a$ if $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x F(t)\,dt = a,$$ where $F(t) = \int_0^t f(u)\,du$. In that sense, since $\int_0^t \sin u\,du = 1 - \cos t$, $\sin$ is C-integrable to $1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is there anything more we can do with that?  And could you post it as an answer?

Comment: Let us not worry at this point about unusual notions of summation. What we can observe for sure is that *it is not true* that $\lim_{p\to\infty}\cos(p)=0$.   For $\cos(2n\pi)=1$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am not disagreeing, but $\lim_{p\to\infty}\cos(p)=0$ is at least reasonable in my defense.

Comment: @SimpleArt: Not from the usual definition of limit. Nor from a casual glance at  a picture of the curve, which bounces back and forth from $-1$ to $1$ forever.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, that is true.  I agree, the limit probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that neither $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin x\,dx$ nor $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cos x$ exist in the conventional meanings of these symbols. But similar to how one can assign more or less reasonable values to some divergent series, one can also assign more or less reasonable values to some divergent integrals.

Recall that a series $\sum_n a_n$ is Cesàro-summable if the sequence of arithmetic means of the partial sums converges,

$$(a_n)\quad\text{Cesàro-summable } :\mspace{-5mu}\iff \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k = 0}^n \sum_{m = 0}^k a_m\quad\text{exists.}$$

Analogously, we might call a locally integrable function $f\colon [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ C-integrable if the limit of the arithmetic means of the partial integrals,

$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \biggl(\int_0^t f(u)\,du\biggr)dt,$$

exists. If $L := \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ exists, then $f$ is C-integrable, and the C-integral equals $L$, so C-integrability is compatible with integrability, like Cesàro-summability is compatible with summability.

Since $\int_0^t \sin u\,du = 1 - \cos t$, we have

$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \biggl(\int_0^t \sin u\,du\biggr)dt = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x 1 - \cos t\,dt = 1 - \frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1,$$

so $\sin$ is C-integrable to $1$.

There are other ways than Cesàro-summation to assign values to (some) divergent series, and we can also use other means to assign values to divergent integrals. For example, if $f$ is (locally integrable and) of at most polynomial growth, then

$$I_{\varepsilon}(f) := \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\varepsilon t}f(t)\,dt$$

exists for every $\varepsilon > 0$, and if $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} I_{\varepsilon}(f)$ exists, we can assign that value to the integral. If $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable (improperly Riemann-integrable), the limit exists and equals the Lebesgue integral by the dominated convergence theorem (resp. it equals the improper Riemann integral).

For $\sin$, we find

\begin{align}
\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\varepsilon x}\sin x\,dx &= \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{+\infty} e^{(i -\varepsilon)x} - e^{-(i+\varepsilon)x}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2i}\biggl[\frac{1}{\varepsilon - i} - \frac{1}{\varepsilon + i}\biggr]\\
&= \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2 + 1},
\end{align}

so also this method leads to the value $1$.

Comment: Near the end/middle was a funky diagonal arrow in a limit.  I am unsure if you meant to use a regular arrow.

Comment: It's meant to indicate that $\varepsilon$ decreases towards $0$. It's also written $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ with a vertical arrow, $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ means the same thing. Since I've explicitly restricted $\varepsilon$ to strictly positive values, writing $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0}$ would probably also have been legitimate.

Comment: Does not it simply assume that $\cos(\infty)=0$, and then it comes to $-\cos(\infty)-(-\cos(0))=1$?

Comment: @Anixx No. What gave you that idea?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer if your answer is 1 and we know that $-\cos(0)$=-1, it follows that you count $\cos(\infty)$ as 0.

Comment: Nonsense, @Anixx. I don't use anything like $\cos (\infty)$ at all. While one could give meaning to that expression [we could simply define it as meaning $\frac{43\pi}{60}$, why not?], I don't see a way to give a meaning to it that makes using it in any way helpful here. If $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)$ exists, then it can be quite useful to define $f(\infty)$ as that limit. But the limit doesn't exist for $f = \cos$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I see, the sequence of integrals over semi-periods seems to be 2,0,2,0,2,0... This intuitively implies the sum should be 1 (as an average). The problem with it is that the distance between the semi-periods is not the same as from the mid of the first semi-period and zero. Also, the semi-periods are not separated by intervals of one (which is lesser problem).

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Csin+x+dx+&x=11&y=4

Comment: @TehRod Yes, the integral doesn't exist in the classical sense. I say that in the first sentence of the answer. But like for divergent series, there are methods to assign values to certain divergent integrals. Sometimes some of these methods are sensible.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I had no idea

Answer (score 4):

No. The integral doesn't convergent and the limit doesn't exist given the periodicity of the functions involved.

Answer (score -1):

By definition of the improper integral,

$$\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\,dx=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t\sin(x)\,dx.$$

By the fundamental theorem, this is also

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}(1-\cos(t)).$$

Hence the requested relation is

$$\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\,dx=1-\lim_{t\to\infty}\cos(t),$$ which is perfectly undefined.